# How to show and hide pop up onclick in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend, web-deployment

i have a pop up class called "query-pop-up", i want to show and hide popup onclick in pure js. How to achicve that.

SHould i use addEverntListerner, or somethinge else.

Please let me know using this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to Javascript myself, but from what I understand in your question, it seems that you are doing some form of web design and are likely also using HTML and CSS.

You could probably use an addEventListener method, but I think the jquery toggle method would be more convenient because it allows you to 'toggle' between hide and show for all elements. Without further detail, I can't really recommend a specific implementation, but I would suggest to check out the following links:

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Hope I was somewhat helpful! Good luck! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).